# WIX Editor - form where you can select dates which will be pasted into adress http://...com#/&from=2021-07-16&to=2021-07-17

Tags: editor, velo

Please help me!!!

I can see there are some calendars available in WIX Editor you can use on your site.

Now, how to make this: you click on calendars where you can select date of arrival and departure (f.example 2021-07-16 and 2021-07-17) and click a button (confirm) which picks up those dates and forward you to the new site where those dates will be pasted into address http://....com#/&from=2021-07-16&to=2021-07-17

Thank you!!!

Comment: Should probably ask Wix support.

Answer (score 1):

**UI**

1. Add a *form* component
2. Add 2 date fields
3. Add a submit button

[image]

(I don't know of a way of setting range of dates in a single datepicker)

**Code**

```js
$w.onReady(function () {
    // 
    $w('#datePicker1').onChange(e => {
        const fromDate = new Date(e.target.value);
        fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
        $w('#datePicker2').value = fromDate;
        // this way the user couldn't select an "to" date lower than the "from" date
        $w('#datePicker2').minDate = fromDate;
    });
    $w('#wixForms1').onWixFormSubmit(e => {
        const fromDate = e.fields[0].fieldValue.toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');
        const toDate = e.fields[1].fieldValue.toLocaleDateString('fr-CA');

        wixLocation.to(`https://example.com/?start=${fromDate}&end=${toDate}`);
    });
});
```

https://moshef9.wixsite.com/dates-range

Comment: Note that if you change the value of an input element on a Wix Form it won't record the value in the database. If you want to pick up any value (modified or set by code) you need to build the form yourself using the Editor's input elements and use the Wix Data API to submit the data.

Comment: Good to know! OP didn't mention database though, only a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Thanks Mosh! I'm a huge step forward!
I make a simple form with 2 dates an "submit" button.
I pasted your code on my Wix site.
If I click "submit" button then ...nothing happens;(
Why???
I'd like to just say that imported wixLocation from 'wix-location' and everything
seems to be correct.